# unique enhancement for derived categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I have two questions concerning the existence and uniqueness of enhancements in the following cases:
i.) Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$ algebra of finite global dimension. Does the triangulated category $D^b(\mathrm{mod}A)$ of finitely generated $A$ modules admit (unique) enhancement?

ii.) let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme over $k$. Then $D^b(X)$ has a unique enhancement. What is about admissible subcategories $R\subset D^b(X)$...Do they have (unique) enhancements?

Comment: hi Aleksa, may I ask what kind of enhancement are you thinking of?

Comment: @FernandoMuro, why would it matter?  Surely Aleksa means some kind of stable linear (infty,1)-categorical enhancements.

Comment: Adeel, maybe it matters, maybe not, let Aleksa say.

Comment: I imagine ii) should be true, but I'm not familiar enough with the techniques of Lunts-Orlov to be sure.

Comment: @FernandoMuro, ok.  I am just wondering what possible difference there could be, since the various models of stable linear (infty,1)-categories, including pretriangulated dg-categories, are known to be equivalent, as you of course know.

Comment: Adeel, I don't know what you mean, there are different kinds of enhancements, not all of them equivalent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12300/discussion-between-adeel-and-fernando-muro)

Comment: The enhancement in both cases should be a pretriangulated DG-categories just as assumend in the work of Lunts-Orlov.

Comment: Maybe the first case can be seen as follows for commutative $A$: Take $\mathrm{Spec}(A)=X$, then one has equivalence of abelian categories $\mathrm{coh}(X)\simeq \mathrm{mod}(A)$. Hence $D^b(X)\simeq D^b(\mathrm{mod}(A))$. Since $X$ is a quasi-projective scheme over a field $k$ we conclude by Theorem 2.13 in the work of Lunts-Orlov that $D^b(X)$ and hence $D^b(\mathrm{mod}(A))$ has a unique enhancement. But for the second case I have no idea...